# Moving a file to the prefetch folder make openning it fast?

Tags: operating-systems

I have an excel file, that I mostly open. If I put that file in the prefetch folder will make its openning quick?

If no do you have other suggestion to make a file open fast?

Thank you

Comment: Open it from an [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) rather than [HDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) and it'd open faster for the disk IO operations.

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The Prefetch folder is a system folder intended for the exclusive use of the system. The files in this folder must follow a very specific format that has not been fully documented. It was never intended that the user would ever add files to this folder.

Files with the PF extension are trace files used to improve load time of applications. Do not attempt to create or modify these files. The folder also contains files used by Superfetch. Superfetch makes use of memory that would otherwise be free to contain portions of frequently accessed files. There is no facility for the user to manipulate this.

The best way to improve performance in accessing files is to put them on an SSD.